# Can't connect to www.example.com with https

Tags: python, dns

I'm trying to get started with the Yocto project Quick Build, and the first `bitbake` command is failing when it tries to check the network availability by fetching `https://www.example.com`. The error message is:

`Fetcher failure for URL: 'https://www.example.com/'. URL https://www.example.com/ doesn't work.`

I know my network is set up correctly (I can use the web normally except for this), and my network has no proxy on it (another common cause of similar issues).

I did a bunch of googling around this issue, and found suggestions to try using `wget` and python directly to check the availability. Like so:

I tried connecting with wget and got these results.

With `http`:

```
$ wget http://www.example.com
Resolving www.exampe.com (www.exampe.com)... 72.52.179.174
Connecting to www.exampe.com (www.exampe.com)|72.52.179.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://ww4.exampe.com [following]
--2018-12-20 22:43:03--  http://ww4.exampe.com/
Resolving ww4.exampe.com (ww4.exampe.com)... 192.64.147.152
Connecting to ww4.exampe.com (ww4.exampe.com)|192.64.147.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 842 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

And with `https`:

```
$ wget https://www.example.com
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 198.105.254.23, 198.105.244.23
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|198.105.254.23|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|198.105.244.23|:443... failed: Connection refused.
```

I then tried the same checks using python from the command line like
so:

```
$ python -c 'import urllib; print urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.com").read()'
$ python -c 'import urllib; print urllib.urlopen("https://www.example.com").read()'
```

These both failed with this error:

```
<stacktrace omitted>
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Finally, checking at the socket connection level with `telnet`
revealed that the trying to connect to socket 443 at www.example.com
failed completely.

```
$ telnet www.example.com 443
Trying 198.105.254.23...
Trying 198.105.244.23...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output from the debugging commands in the question
you'll see that the domain `www.example.com` is resolving to at least
3 different IP addresses, and perhaps most importantly, different IP
addresses are being resolved depending on the protocol passed to wget.

A lot of googling seemed to point to the fact that perhaps my python
CA certificates were not set up correctly (a problem in many
distributions shortly after python 2.7 came out, but not I think
anymore).

In the end, I ended up changing my default nameserver from the default
that my router had configured (probably specific to my ISP,
CenturyLink) and changed to using CloudFlare's public DNS servers at
1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, and I started resolving `www.example.com` to
93.184.216.34 and the problem went away.

My best guess as to what was happening is that my ISP (or the backbone
ISP that they connect to) has their own personal server for
`www.example.com` and that server does not have HTTPS set up.

Comment: `example.com` had an expired SSL cert briefly recently I believe.

Comment: interesting.  I don't think that would cause the behavior I was seeing though, especially a total refusal to connect to port 443 with telnet.